# Display formating of javascript object, through node

Tags: javascript, object

I've been puzzled by this for a while. Let's take this simple object:

```
let animalList = {
  animals : ["dog","cat","horse"],
  colors : ["blue","red"]
};

console.log(animalList);
```

It gives me this output:

```
{ animals: [ 'dog', 'cat', 'horse' ],
  colors: [ 'blue', 'red' ] }
```

Let's say I wanted this output, instead (I understand it's purely cosmetic):

```
{
  animals: [ "dog", "cat", "horse" ],
  colors: [ "blue", "red" ]
}
```

Where does node stores it's display properties? (the quotation symbol to use, the spacing and the newlines to display an object, and so on)

Comment: It is properties of a browser. Object itself doesn't have *formatting* properties.

Comment: That's probably hidden deeply within the browser.

Comment: At the moment, I'm running this from the shell, but I came to the same conclusion you both did. That being said, the question keep popping up at my school, so I thought I'd turn to people with more knowledge than I do, in hope of getting a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JSON.stringify` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)) for some formatting:

```js
let animalList = {
  animals : ["dog","cat","horse"],
  colors : ["blue","red"]
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(animalList, null, 2));
```

But to customize how new lines are handled you would have to make your own obj->string function such as:

```js
let prettyPrint = (obj, indent = 0, indentStep = 2) => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj))
    return `[ ${obj.map(a => prettyPrint(a, indent + 1, indentStep)).join(', ')}]`;
  if (typeof obj === 'string')
    return `"${obj}"`;
  if (typeof obj === 'number')
    return number;
  if (typeof obj === 'undefined')
    return 'undefined';
  if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    let spaces = ' '.repeat((indent + 1) * indentStep);
    let inside = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) =>
        `${spaces}${key}: ${prettyPrint(value, indent + 1, indentStep)}`);
    return `{\n${inside.join(',\n')}\n},`;
  }
};

let animalList = {
  animals: ["dog", "cat", "horse"],
  colors: ["blue", "red"]
};

console.log(prettyPrint(animalList));
```